Prove that $2 (a+2)^2 (2-b)\leq \left((a+2)^2 (1-b) (2-b)+2\right) (a b+2)^2$ for $a\geq0$ and $0\leq b\leq 1$
I would like to prove that, for all for $a\geq0$ and $0\leq b\leq 1$, $$2 \leq \left[ (1-b) +\frac{2}{(a+2)^2 (2-b)}\right] (a b+2)^2.$$
Mathematica confirms that this statement is true. But I am having a hard time writing a proof.

I have tried to find a way to apply the AM-GM inequality (e.g., I know that I can use it to bound $(ab+2)^2\geq 8ab$).
I have also tried using Cauchy-Schwarz to bound $(a+2)^2$ from above.
Any hints about how to proceed would be warmly appreciated.

By using maple, you can try to prove the long item in bracket is greater than zero $-\frac{\left(b-1\right) \left(a^{4} b^{3}-2 a^{4} b^{2}+4 a^{3} b^{3}-4 a^{3} b^{2}+4 a^{2} b^{3}-8 a^{3} b+8 a^{2} b^{2}-26 a^{2} b+16 a ,b^{2}-4 a^{2}-16 a b-16 a+16 b-24\right)}{\left(a+2\right)^{2} \left(-2+b\right)}$

Let $f=\left(1-b +\frac{2}{\left(a +2\right)^{2} \left(2-b \right)}\right) \left(a b +2\right)^{2}$. Then
$$
f-2=\frac{1-b}{(a+2)^2(2-b)}P(a,b)
$$
where
$$
P(a,b)=-a^{4} b^{3}+2 a^{4} b^{2}-4 a^{3} b^{3}+4 a^{3} b^{2}-4 a^{2} b^{3}+8 a^{3} b -8 a^{2} b^{2}+26 a^{2} b -16 a \,b^{2}+4 a^{2}+16 a b +16 a -16 b +24
$$
Assume everywhere from now that $a\ge 0$, $b\in[0,1]$.
Next,
$$
\frac{\partial^3 P}{\partial a^3}=24b(2-b)(ab + b + 1)\ge 0
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial a^2}|_{a=0}=8(1-b^3) +52b- 16b^2 \ge 0
$$
so $\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial a^2}\ge 0$, and together with
$$
\frac{\partial P}{\partial a}|_{a=0}=16(1+b-b^2)\ge 0
$$
we get $\frac{\partial P}{\partial a}\ge 0$.
Finally
$$
P(0,b)=24-16b\ge 0
$$
hence $P(a,b)\ge 0$ for all $a\ge 0$ and thus $f-2\ge 0$.

Note that $\mathrm{LHS} = \mathrm{RHS}$ when $b = 1$. The following manipulations are based on $b=1$.
First, we have $\frac{1}{2-b} \ge b$ (with equality when $b=1$).
It suffices to prove that
$$2 \leq \left[ (1-b) +\frac{2}{(a+2)^2}b\right] (a b+2)^2,$$
which is written as
$$\left(\frac{2a^2}{(a+2)^2} - a^2\right)b^3 + \left(\frac{8a}{(a+2)^2} + a^2 - 4a\right)b^2 + \left(\frac{8}{(a+2)^2} + 4a - 4\right)b + 2\ge 0.$$
Since $b^3 \le b^2$ and $\frac{2a^2}{(a+2)^2} - a^2 \le 0$, it suffices to prove that
$$\left(\frac{2a^2}{(a+2)^2} - a^2\right)b^2 + \left(\frac{8a}{(a+2)^2} + a^2 - 4a\right)b^2 + \left(\frac{8}{(a+2)^2} + 4a - 4\right)b + 2\ge 0,$$
or
$$\left(\frac{2a^2}{(a+2)^2} + \frac{8a}{(a+2)^2} - 4a\right)b^2 + \left(\frac{8}{(a+2)^2} + 4a - 4\right)b + 2\ge 0.$$
Since $b^2 \le b$ and $\frac{2a^2}{(a+2)^2} + \frac{8a}{(a+2)^2} - 4a \le 0$, it suffices to prove that
$$\left(\frac{2a^2}{(a+2)^2} + \frac{8a}{(a+2)^2} - 4a\right)b + \left(\frac{8}{(a+2)^2} + 4a - 4\right)b + 2\ge 0,$$
or
$$2 - 2b \ge 0$$
which is true.
We are done.

I manged to prove the inequality with a combination of algebra and calculus:
First, algebraically, we can rearrange the the inequality as
$$\frac{(a+2)^2 (2-b) \left[2-(1-b) (a b+2)^2\right]}{2 (a b+2)^2}\leq 1.$$
Differentiating the left-hand side yields
$$\frac{\partial \text{LHS}}{\partial a}=-\frac{(a+2) (2-b) (1-b) }{(a b+2)^3}\left(a^3 b^3+6 a^2 b^2+12 a b+4\right).$$
Everything in the fraction is non-negative, so this derivative is clearly non-positive. Thus, make the left-hand side of the inequality as big as possible by letting $a\rightarrow0$.
We are then left to show $-2 + 5 b - 2 b^2\leq1$. This is easily done because the right-hand side is increasing in $b$ and equal to $1$ when $b=1$.
